# How can a module with setup.py installed using Cython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

First I've no experience with python. I just want to install a module in blender which comes with a setup.py. It seems that I need Cython to install that. I added Cython to PYTHONPATH  and the bin folder to the PATH. This error is shown:

```
python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext})
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 917, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 936, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 569, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 936, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 936, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Cython-0.19.1\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 163, in run
    _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 354, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "C:\Cython-0.19.1\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 170, in build_extensions
    ext.sources = self.cython_sources(ext.sources, ext)
  File "C:\Cython-0.19.1\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 181, in cython_sources
    from Cython.Compiler.Main \
  File "C:\Cython-0.19.1\Cython\Compiler\Main.py", line 302
    except UnicodeDecodeError#, e:
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Versions are: Python 3.3 / Windows7 64 / Cython-0.19.1

Any ideas, what should I try?

Comment: Uh, what? Your Cython install appears to be damaged (that really is illegal syntax). Consider reinstalling, perhaps?

Comment: There is a [Windows installer](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cython) for Cython on Python 3.3; try that maybe?

Comment: @nneonneo This worked, do you want to add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Cython installation was damaged somehow. You might want to consider getting a fresh installation, perhaps from the [Cython Windows installer for Python 3.3](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cython).